# React-Navigation: Use/Change header title with Redux state

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

Is it possible to access the whole Redux state inside the React Navigation's header title?

The [official docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/headers) says that the state corresponding to the navigation is accessible:

```
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: ({ state }) => `Chat with ${state.params.user}`
  };
```

But I wish to access other parts of my Redux state, with the title updating when that state updates. Is that possible today?

Comment: What about react-helmet connected to redux?

Answer (score 12):

this is possible with a little workaround. I would not even call this a workaround either I would call this a great feature :-)

you just have to use a new component in your header like this:

```
static navigationOptions = {
    header: (navigation) => {
        return <HomeViewTitle />;
    }
}
```

and then you can connect in my case HomeViewTitle with the redux state:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
    View,
    Text
} from 'react-native';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';


class HomeViewTitle extends Component {

    render() {

        return (

            <View style={{height: 64, backgroundColor: '#000000', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', paddingTop: 20}}>
                <Text style={{color: '#FFFFFF', fontSize: 17, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Home</Text>
            </View>

        );

    }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return state;
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HomeViewTitle);
```

then you have your redux state as props in HomeViewTitle and you can set the header dynamic

Comment: So it's possible to put images, buttons etc in the header? How does that render?

Comment: yes it's possible to put basically everything in the header. It renders the same way every other redux connected component would render. In my case I have a image in the header which is not available at the app start. Once the app is loaded it makes a json request and loads the image into the redux store. When the image is in the store it updates the HeaderViewTitle and the image gets displayed

Comment: However with this method you lose all the auto platform styling features that come out of the box with react-navigation. :(

Comment: which styling do you mean? Either you want to use defaults from react-navigation or do it by your own, just make your components look like you want

Answer (score 7):

An easier way to do this that preserves the styles of the header component is to utilize React-Navigation's [`getParam` and `setParams`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html). In `navigationOptions` you would have:

```js
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
   return {
      title: navigation.getParam('title', 'DEFAULT VALUE IF PARAM IS NOT DEFINED'),
   };
}
```

and then in `componentWillMount()` you would have:

```js
componentWillMount(){
   this.props.navigation.setParams({ 'title': this.props.title })
}
```

make sure to dispatch the title to props

```js
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    title: state.titleSavedInState,
  }
};
```

The above is sufficient if you are not making any changes to the state before the state of the component (note that updating the state in redux only updates the props of the components) is updated again. However, if you are going to do be making changes while the component is open, you also need to use:

```js
componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
    if(this.props.navigation.getParam('title', 'DEFAULT') != this.props.titleSavedInState)
    this.props.navigation.setParams({ 'title': this.props.titleSavedInState })
}
```

Comment: Hey, I want to use passed param in the next screen, I'm tried to do that with

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        return {
            title: navigation.getParam('providerName'),
        };
    }
 render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>Provider Profile</Text>
                {console.log("@name", this.props.navigation.getParam('providerName'))} // i can get the name here
            </View>
        );
    }
```