# How to use StackNavigator with Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

Could please somebody help me to manage with StackNavigator and Redux integration? Everything looks pretty simple, but doesn't work.

**index.ios.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  AppRegistry
} from 'react-native'

import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import configureStore from './configureStore'

import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import Welcome from "./screens/welcome";
import Accounts from "./screens/accounts";

const store = configureStore()

const Nav = StackNavigator({
  Welcome: {
    screen: Welcome,
  },
  Accounts: {
    screen: Accounts,
  },
});

const TestApp = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Nav />
  </Provider>
)

AppRegistry.registerComponent('TestApp', () => RNRedux)
```

**configureStore.js**

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import rootReducer from './reducers'

export default function configureStore() {
  let store = createStore(rootReducer)
  return store
}
```

**reducers/index.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import accounts from './accounts'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  accounts
})

export default rootReducer
```

**screens/accounts.js**

```
import React from 'react';

import { StyleSheet, Text, View, button } from 'react-native';
import { ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export class Accounts extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Accounts',
  }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    state = {}
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View>
        {
          this.props.accounts.map((l, i) => (
            <ListItem
              key={i}
              title={l.title}
              subtitle={l.hash}
            />
          ))
        }
      </View>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return {
    accounts: state.accounts
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
)(Accounts)
```

**reducers/accounts.js**

```
const initialState = {
  accounts: [
    {
      title: "Bitcoin Slash Fund",
      hash: "0x83247jfy344fgg",
    },
  ],
}

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

When I navigate to **Accounts** screen, I get the error

`TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...this.props.state.accounts.map...');`

Accounts screen seems not to be actually connected to Redux, and I can't figure out why. Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Its not about cannot connect to Reduce, it's about your **props** cannot load data into list. Please check your data props again pls.

Comment: There is no `accounts` property in Props, I've checked already. I believe it's because  `mapStateToProps` can't load it from the state, no?

Comment: U can **console.log** the **state** to see your props account got initialized yet.

Comment: Currently I'm on the ways and no laptop with, i really wish to help so much.

Comment: Thanks a lot! There is no console in react-devtools, and I don't know where to find it in emulator, but JSON.stringlify(state) shows an empty string in **screens/accounts.js**

Comment: I see u might make some confuse about accounts.js **reducer** with **screen**
As I see you export **accountsReducer** but I didn't see your import it into **combineReducer**... Please check

Comment: It's ok, `import accounts from './accounts'` - both **accounts.js** and **index.js** are in the same **reducers** folder

Comment: and I already removed function's name in export, now it's anonymous.

Comment: This answer helped me https://stackoverflow.com/a/44846741/7626277

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
function mapStateToProps (state) {
  // Just FYI here you can use console.log to see the state)
  // console.log(state);
  return {
    accounts: state.accounts.accounts
  }
}
```

you could see console.log output in Xcode or in AndroidStudio.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Redux to manage the state of navigator.  refer to this official doc: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/redux-integration.html

In my case, if you just want the title of navigator changed when the Redux state changes, just use `screenProps`, refer to: [Passing screenProps to a tab navigator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47026936/passing-screenprops-to-a-tab-navigator)

e.g. in your App.js  `render` method, pass screenProps into the target component,

```
import { LoginStackNavigator } from './navigators/LoginStackNavigator'

render () {

  return (
    <LoginStackNavigator screenProps={
      {
        // Step1. pass the value into the navigator component instance. 
        tradeTitle: i18n.t('trade', {locale: this.props.language}),
      }
    }/>
  )
}
```

and in the related file, ( such as `LoginStackNavigator.js` in my case),

```
import { AppTabNavigator } from '../navigators/AppTabNavigator'
export const LoginStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Trade: {
    screen: AppTabNavigator
  }
  //...
```

and in the final file ( `AppTabNavigator`)

```
export const AppTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  TradeStackNavigator: {
    screen: TradeStackNavigator,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation, navigationOptions, screenProps}) => {
      return {
        // Step2. here use screenProps to retrieve the value passed in . 
        tabBarLabel: screenProps.tradeTitle,
      }
    }
```